# Install VS Code on Windows through Powershell / command prompt?

Tags: windows, shell, visual-studio-code, command-line

Is there a way to install Install VS Code on Windows through Powershell / command prompt commands ? as in linux with "sudo apt install ..."

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Complementing [@Mohammed El Sayed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5013943/mohammed-el-sayed) great answer that uses Choco, the now [Microsoft official package manager WinGet](https://winget.run/pkg/Microsoft/VisualStudioCode) can let you do this as well

```
winget install -e --id Microsoft.VisualStudioCode
```

Note `-e` matches exact string (instead of substring) and `--id` limits usage to ID of application. [More on args here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/install)

For more info on customising the installation see this [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/discussions/1798).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Choco

```
choco install vscode.install
```

Ref:
https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/vscode.install

Answer (score 1):

You can use a customized function that I created in this repository [VSCode Installation](https://github.com/ansasi/VSCode-powershell-installation)

This is the code:

```
function Install-VSC-Windows {
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateSet('local','global')]
        [string[]]$Scope = 'global',

        [parameter()]
        [ValidateSet($true,$false)]
        [string]$CreateShortCut = $true
    )

    # Windows Version x64
    # Define the download URL and the destination
    $Destination = "$env:TEMP\vscode_installer.exe"
    $VSCodeUrl = "https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=win32-x64"

    # User Installation
    if ($Scope  -eq 'local') {
        $VSCodeUrl = $VSCodeUrl + '-user'
    }

    $UnattendedArgs = '/verysilent /mergetasks=!runcode'

    # Download VSCode installer
    Write-Host Downloading VSCode
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $VSCodeUrl -OutFile $Destination # Install VS Code silently
    Write-Host Download finished

    # Install VSCode
    Write-Host Installing VSCode
    Start-Process -FilePath $Destination -ArgumentList $UnattendedArgs -Wait -Passthru
    Write-Host Installation finished

    # Remove installer
    Write-Host Removing installation file
    Remove-Item $Destination
    Write-Host Installation file removed

    # Create Shortcut
    if ($CreateShortCut -eq $true)
    {
        Create-Shortcut -ShortcutName 'Visual Studio Code' -TargetPath 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe'
    }
}

function Create-Shortcut {
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [string[]]$ShortcutName,

        [parameter()]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [string]$TargetPath
    )

    Write-Host Creating Shortcut
    $WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$Home\Desktop\$ShortcutName.lnk")
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetPath
    $Shortcut.Save()
    Write-Host Shortcut created
}

# Call the function
Install-VSC-Windows
```